# exit() in python interpreter not working after overriding

Tags: python-2.7, python-internals

I was working on my local python 2.7 interpreter to test some code logic. 
As, the command to close the interpreter is "exit()", I assigned a variable like,

```
exit = False
```

After trying out some calculations, when I wanted to quit out of my interpreter and gave

```
exit()
```

it threw following error,

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'bool' object is not callable
```

I know have overridden a system variable maybe but is it so easy to do that? And even If I did, when I tried to assign it to

```
exit = True
```

it keeps throwing me error like "bool object is not callable"
So, what went wrong here?

Comment: you can use `quit()` too, but you'd better not override builtin...but wait, why are you assigning it to True or False exactly ?

Comment: Okay..I was trying to write a check variable which have a boolean value..say if inside a while loop only if exit = False and will quit once, exit = True.

Comment: so better use `can_exit` instead, no ?

Comment: okay, my question is more like - why there was no error thrown while trying to assign a boolean value to 'exit' or 'quit' variable?

Comment: because [`"we are all consenting adults here"`](https://python-guide-chinese.readthedocs.io/zh_CN/latest/writing/style.html#we-are-all-consenting-adults)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I know have overridden a system variable maybe but is it so easy to do that?

What you’ve done is shadowed a builtin name with a global name.<sup>1</sup> That’s perfectly legal to do, and in fact sometimes it’s useful. For example:

- Global namespaces are the same thing as module namespaces. If you weren’t allowed to define a shadowing `exit` in your module, `sys` wouldn’t be allowed to define `sys.exit`. And the same for `io.open`, `codecs.open`, and `gzip.open`. And `numpy.min` and `pandas.apply`. And so on.
- One of the recommended ways to write dual-version code that works with both 2.7 and 3.x involves using [`future`](https://pypi.org/project/future/) and putting 3.x-style `zip`, etc. into your globals.
- Sometimes there are builtins that you don’t care about—they may even be undocumented, or [documented as “legacy” functions that should have been deprecated back in 2.1 and removed in 2.4 but are still hanging around in 2.7](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#non-essential-built-in-funcs). There’s no reason you should be forced to avoid those names. Especially if you’re writing code on a different interpreter or version that doesn’t even have those names, and then want to run it on one that does.
- Various quick&dirty interactive-interpreter things that I don’t want to encourage, but we all do them occasionally.

More generally, shadowing builtins with globals is the same thing as shadowing builtins, globals, or nonlocals with locals, so it would be pretty strange to ban one without banning the other.

More generally still, Python is designed around the “consenting adults” idea. It doesn’t go out of its way to protect you from everything that might possibly be used to shoot yourself in the foot. There are a handful of things that are so rarely useful and so commonly cause trouble (like reassigning `None`) that it was worth adding a bit of code to prevent them, but for the most part, you’re free to do things even if it’s not always a good idea to do them.

---

> And even If I did, when I tried to assign it to

```
exit = True
```

> it keeps throwing me error like "bool object is not callable" So, what went wrong here?

That doesn’t undo what you did. It just means the builtin is now shadowed by a global with the value `True`, instead of one with the value `False`. And `True` is no more callable than `False`.

If you want to undo the shadowing, just delete the shadowing global:

```
del exit
```

---

<sub>1. Python has a few different meanings of “builtin” that don’t quite perfectly overlap. The `exit` function is not compiled as a builtin, and isn’t even part of the `builtins` module until it gets monkeypatched in by `site`, but it is accessed by builtin-namespace lookup, which is the meaning I’m talking about here.</sub>

Comment: Even when I tried to change it back to False, if it was really assigned as False previously.. But that also didn't work..still I kept on getting the same error..why so then?

Comment: @Tyto Assigning `exit = False` when there's already a global named `exit` with the value `False` isn't going to change anything. When you look up `exit`, you still get the global, not the builtin, and the value is still `False`, and you still can't call `False` like a function. If you want to lookup `exit` and find the builtin, you have to delete the global.